# Visual Studio not running when trying to pull data from a SQL table with a foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create an application that connects to a SQL database, and like the title says, whenever I try and pull data from a table that has a foreign key, it doesn't work. It runs, no exceptions are thrown, but the application never opens. I know the connection is correct, as I can pull from individual smaller tables with no foreign keys with no problem, but as soon as I try and inner join them it fails. Any help is much appreciated. Not sure if this will help, but here is the code that I used to create the tables in SQL. Is there something wrong with how they connect?

```
CREATE TABLE GamesLibrary.Publisher
(
    PublisherId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Country NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE GamesLibrary.Developer
(
    DeveloperId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Country NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE GamesLibrary.Genre
(
    GenreId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE GamesLibrary.Console
(
    ConsoleId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE GamesLibrary.Games
(
    GameId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    GenreId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GamesLibrary.Genre(GenreId),
    ConsoleId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GamesLibrary.Console(ConsoleId),
    Rating INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE GamesLibrary.PublishedGame
(
    PublishedGameId Int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DeveloperId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GamesLibrary.Developer(DeveloperId),
    PublisherId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GamesLibrary.Publisher(PublisherId),
    GameId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GamesLibrary.Games(GameId),
    PublishDate INT NOT NULL
);
```

Here is the C# code i'm trying to run unsuccessfully. "scottcon" is just my connection string.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(scottcon);

        string query = "SELECT g.Name AS 'Game Name', g.Rating AS 'Rating', gen.Name AS 'Genre', c.Name AS 'Console' FROM GamesLibrary.Games g INNER JOIN GamesLibrary.Genre gen ON gen.GenreId = g.GenreId INNER JOIN GamesLibrary.Console c ON g.ConsoleId = c.ConsoleId ORDER BY g.GameId";
        /// <summary>
        /// int used to see which table we are at for the search or add function
        /// </summary>
        public int state = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// Default implementation
        /// </summary>
        public GamesLibrary()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// doesnt do anything, fernando added this
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void GamesLibrary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UX_Table.DataSource = GetDataSource(query);
        }

        private DataTable GetDataSource(string sql)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(table);
            UX_Table.DataSource = table;
            connection.Close();

            return table;
        }
```

Comment: And yet you post no code to demonstrate your "pulling". Can you run the same queries in SSMS to see the results you expect based on that query and the data that exists in the referenced objects?

Comment: @SMor Yeah I am able to run them in Azure, and all the data gets pulled up properly. I have edited the original post to show my full VS code.

Comment: @ScottMason, as usual, we create table use  one word, why you use GamesLibrary.Publisher? what is your GamesLibrary?